# How to fix "Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types'"

Tags: swift, if-statement, swiftui

I want to render two different HStacks depending on a value later coming from a backend

```
let list: [ReminderModel] = [ReminderModel(text: "Buy Bananas", closed: true), ReminderModel(text: "Meet John", closed: false), ReminderModel(text: "MMhh", closed: false), ReminderModel(text: "4", closed: false), ReminderModel(text: "5", closed: false), ReminderModel(text: "6", closed: false)]
var current: Int = 0

struct ReminderList: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            list.count%3 == 2 ?
                HStack() {
                    Reminder(closed: list[list.count-2].closed, text: list[list.count-2].text)
                    Reminder(closed: list[list.count-1].closed, text: list[list.count-1].text)
                }
                : //Here is the error
                HStack() {
                    Reminder(closed: list[list.count-1].closed, text: list[list.count-1].text)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types
>   `HStack<TupleView<(Reminder, Reminder)>>` and `HStack<Reminder>`

Comment: You should make an initializer on `Reminder` that takes a `ReminderView`, so that you DRY

Answer (score 3):

As you can see, the two expressions yield different types. It's the same situation as:

```
let x = someCondition ? 1 : "abc"
```

Should `x` be an `Int` or a `String`? Swift has a static type system, so all variables *must* have a type that's known at compile time. Yet, the type here isn't known until run-time, depending on the value of `someCondition()`. In this case, the type has to be set to something that's a super-type (protocol or superclass) of both types. In this case, one example super type is `CustomStringConvertible`. Another possible one is `Any`.

In your case, you can use a type eraser, [`AnyView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anyview), to wrap both arguments, to provide a consistent type of `AnyView`.

An even better solution is to use an if-else block. The SwiftUI view function builder will transform that into a structure that's capable of handling differing views, unlike the conditional operator.

```
let list: [ReminderModel] = [
    ReminderModel(text: "Buy Bananas", closed: true),
    ReminderModel(text: "Meet John", closed: false),
    ReminderModel(text: "MMhh", closed: false),
    ReminderModel(text: "4", closed: false),
    ReminderModel(text: "5", closed: false),
    ReminderModel(text: "6", closed: false),
]

var current: Int = 0

struct ReminderList: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            let last = list.last!

            if list.count % 3 == 2 {
                let secondLast = list.dropLast().last!

                Reminder(closed: secondLast.closed, text: secondLast.text)
                Reminder(closed: last.closed, text: last.text)
           } else {
                HStack() {
                    Reminder(closed: last.closed, text: last.text)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```